# What are good resources for self teaching parallel/concurrent/multithreaded programming techniques?

Tags: reference-request, parallel-computing, concurrency

I’m having a hard time finding anything thorough. I have found some courses with titles like "parallel and concurrent programming in Java", but I'm looking to learn general techniques, not their use in {insert specific technology}.

Comment: Try M. Ben-Ari's book.

Comment: Programming is offtopic here, and book requests are frowned upon on most SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the best way to learn parallelism/concurrency is to learn how it is done in FP languages and then look for the ways to do the same in {your beloved one}. My own list:

- [Communicating sequential processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes) and [Communicating Sequential Processes (CSP), by C. A. R. Hoare (PDF Version)](http://www.usingcsp.com/)
- [Erlang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(programming_language)) and books on Erlang/OTP
- [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](https://simonmar.github.io/pages/pcph.html)
- [Structured Parallel Programming Book](http://parallelbook.com/article/structured-parallel-programming-book)